# Reference Media Manager Image in Component using Tridion Core Service

Tags: core-service, web8, ecl, sdl-tridion

We have Media Manager ECL mounted on SDL Tridion and images are already uploaded on Media Manager. Now i have to link images in Component via Tridion Core service.

How can it be achieved?  Please provide any reference that can be used to link images in component

Comment: Tag the version of the tridion that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Raise support ticket with SDL to get the mountpoint GUI extension installation. After this GUI extension, you will see a mountpoint in the CME, using which you can browse the images from media manager.

For the reference to the media manager integration with SDL, refer: [SDL Tridion Connector 1.1 for SDL Media Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ECLMediaManager_11/concept_CCEBB5B5FDC148D187AAD0AF23C26A06). This reference is for web 8.1, if you are on any other version then you should be able to find something similar for that version also.

**Update based on clarification**

For the purpose of creating components using core service, you will have to add reference to ecl libraries and follow the steps given below:

Load the mountpoint, Search the image by name, Extract ecluri from the searched image, Using ecluri create stub component, using the method:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> CreateOrGetStubUris(IEnumerable<string> eclItemUris)
```

After above steps, you can reference ecluri in the component creation.

Comment: Media Manager GUI extension is already mounted with SDL web 8 but we are creating component dynamically using core service so need the ecl id for linking of image with component.

Comment: "Load the mountpoint, Search the image by name, Extract ecluri from the searched image" Is it manual or using code?

Comment: Using code obviously.. seems you know how to do it manually and make it work ;)

Comment: Great :) i asked as for create stub you mentioned method name but for above not.

Comment: How to load Mountpoint in a Console Application that i am using as of now. I read the Tridion External Content Library Api reference, there are talking  mostly about Developing Templates,Developing Providers and Developing Event Handlers. In my case i have  to interact with ECL content library while using CoreService for creating components.

Comment: @MohdKashif this is a separate question so I would recommend asking it separately so that you get more attention